# I am getting listView.getChildCount(), is 0 after setting the arrayadapter?

Tags: android

I want to load images from facebook and populate in listview, i am able to get list of friends and their info but  i want to set image i am getting getChildCount() 0 , please help,

```
   public static ArrayList<FBUser> fbUserArrayList;
    public static Drawable sharedDrawable;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.friends_list_view);
        this.setTitle("FB Friend List");

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        FriendListAdapter couponsListAdapter = new FriendListAdapter(this,
                fbUserArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(couponsListAdapter);

        couponsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        setFbUsersImage(listView,fbUserArrayList);

    }

    private void setFbUsersImage(final ListView listView,final ArrayList<FBUser> fbUserArrayList) {
                // here am getting 0 ???
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
 ////           
   }

    }
```

Comment: why not use `fbUserArrayList.size()` ? may be list not populated yet

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The ListView has not been drawn yet so it doesn't have any children. Unfortunately there is no callback, like `onResume()`, for when a View has been drawn, but you can use a Runnable to do what you want.

---

**Addition**
Let's make a couple changes in `onCreate()`:

```
listView.setAdapter(couponsListAdapter);
// Remove your calls to notifyDataSetChanged and setFbUsersImage

// Add this Runnable
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        setFbUsersImage(listView,fbUserArrayList);
    }
});
```

You need to make `listView` a field variable just like `fbUserArrayList`. Now `setFbUsersImage()` will be run when the ListView has children.

All that said, if you are trying to modify the row in *any* way, the adapter is the best place to do this.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your answer! But I want to go further and understood this behaviour - do I understood correct that setAdapter doesn't force AdapterView to create its view hierarchy immediately?

Comment: Thankyou! Took me an hour to figure why it wasn't working.

Comment: I was aware why, but did not know how. Thank you sir.